# How to specify multiple conditions in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.3.4.0-3485

I have been trying to import data using sqoop using the following command:

```
sqoop import -libjars /usr/local/bfm/lib/java/jConnect-6/6.0.0/jconn3-6.0.0.jar --connect jdbc:sybase:db --username user --password 'pwd' --driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver --query 'SELECT  a.* from table1 a,table2 b where b.run_group=a.run_group  and a.date<"7/22/2016" AND $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/user/a/ --verbose --hive-import --hive-table default.temp_a --split-by id
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid column name '7/22/2016'
```

I have tried enclosing the query in double quotes, but then it says:

```
CONDITIONS: Undefined variable.
```

Tried several combinations of single/double quotes and escaping $CONDITIONS and using a --where switch as well.

PS: The conditions are non numeric. (It works for cases like where x<10 or so, but not in case where it's a string or date)

Comment: When you tried enclosing the whole query in double quotes, and the other strings in single ones, did you add the backslash  before $CONDITIONS? Something like this: --query "SELECT a.* (...) and a.date<'7/22/2016' AND \$CONDITIONS"   I read you tried escaping the $conditions as well, but it's just to be sure about the different combinations you tried.

Comment: Is this query working on RDBMS client: `SELECT  a.* from table1 a,table2 b where b.run_group=a.run_group and a.date<"7/22/2016"`

Comment: If it's working then try `"SELECT  a.* from table1 a,table2 b where b.run_group=a.run_group and a.date<'7/22/2016' AND \$CONDITIONS"` as suggested by Jaime

Comment: @JaimeCr : I tried that. It says Undefined variable. :/

Comment: @devツ: Yup! Tried the exact same command. No luck.

Comment: Have you guys personally executed that command successfully? I'm trying to narrow down if it is something particular to a sqoop version,

Comment: Are you able to the command `SELECT a.* from table1 a,table2 b where b.run_group=a.run_group and a.date<"7/22/2016"` on RDBMS JDBC client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that can be used: -options-file

Copy the query in your options file and use the switch.

The options file might be as:

```
--query
select * \
from table t1 \
where t1.field="text" \
and t1.value="value" \
and $CONDITIONS
```

Note: Not sure if it was a particular version issue or not but --query directly in the command just refused to work with $CONDITIONS. (Yes, I tried escaping it with \ and several other combinations of quotations)

Answer (score 0):

In your command `--split-by=id` should be `--split-by=a.id`, I would use `join` instead of adding extra `where` condition, also I would convert date to (specified string value) `VARCHR` (using sybase specific function)

```
sqoop import -libjars /usr/local/bfm/lib/java/jConnect-6/6.0.0/jconn3-6.0.0.jar \
--connect jdbc:sybase:db \
--username user \
--password 'pwd' \
--driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver \
--query "SELECT  a.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.id where a.run_group=b.run_group and convert(varchar, a.date, 101) < '7/22/2016' AND \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/user/a/ \
--verbose \
--hive-import \
--hive-table default.temp_a \
--split-by a.id
```

Comment: Still no luck. $CONDITIONS seem to work with integer based conditions. E.g: id<1000 in the where clause works, but date field doesn't. Even string comparisons do not work for that matter. (Ones that are char and varchar fields, with and without applying the convert function)

Comment: can you `AND (1 = 1)` instead of `AND $CONDITIONS`?

Comment: if that does not work - tried to find any existing issues in sqoop for `$CONDITIONS` - if you dont find anything similar to your issue - you can submit JIRA ticket - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1061?jql=project%20%3D%20SQOOP%20AND%20text%20~%20%22%24CONDITIONS%22

Comment: does `select` query works on `sybase` itself and gives you expected results?